# Ubuntu 19.10 change gnome-shell font

Tags: fonts, gnome-shell

In **Ubuntu 19.10** the `gnome-shell.css` location is:

**/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css**

Edit `gnome-shell.css` as administrator. Then search for

```
stage {
  font-family:
```

Just add your desired font-family name. For example:

```
stage {
  font-family: Fira Sans, Cantarell, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #3D3D3D; }
```

Done. Save it and log-out and log-in again.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This is a Q and A website. If you want to post a tutorial about how to do something, please form it as a question, and then answer you own question below where it says 'Your Answer`, and accept it.